# Ruby XOR bit wise manipulation cryptography exercise

Tags: ruby, cryptography, bit-manipulation, bitwise-xor

I am trying to convert a message into a ASCII hex value string and back again. However, I am having a lot of trouble with my ^ bit wise XOR operator. I've spent the last 4 hours searching stackoverflow's similar questions on XOR and bit wise manipulation, but no suggestion I've seen has fixed this issue yet.

I have a RakeTest file, which the following made up test:

```
def test_xor
    key = 'hi'
    msg = 'Hello There, how are you?'
    key_trunc = key
    key_trunc << key while key.length < msg.length
    key_trunc = Decrypt.truncate_key key_trunc, msg.length

    ct = Decrypt.xor msg, key_trunc
    assert_equal('200c040507493c010d1b0d454801071e48081a0c4810071c57', ct)
end
```

I've worked out by hand (and verified with an online hex converter) that the correct ASCII hex result should be what is above. Here is my Decrypt module:

```
module Decrypt

  # Returns an array of ASCII Hex values
  def self.to_hex_array(str_hex)
    raise ArgumentError 'Argument is not a string.' unless str_hex.is_a? String

    result = str_hex.unpack('C*').map { |e| e.to_s 16 }

    result
  end

  def self.to_str_from_hex_array(hex_str)
    return [hex_str].pack 'H*'
  end

  def self.xor(msg, key)

    msg = self.to_hex_array msg
    key = self.to_hex_array key
    xor = []

    (0...msg.length).each do |i|
      xor.push msg[i] ^ key[i]
    end

    return xor.join
  end

  def self.truncate_key(str, len)
    str = str.to_s[0...len] if str.length > len

    return str

  end

end
```

I've confirmed in two separate rake test functions that `to_hex_array` and `to_str_from_hex_array` are working correctly. When I run the above rake test, I get a `'NoMethodError: undefined method '^' for "48":String`. 48 is the beginning hex value, and obviously Strings cannot undergo bit wise operations, but I have tried every method I could find to convert the values such that '^' will operate correctly.

The closest I can get (no error thrown) is to change the operation inside the loop to `msg[i].hex ^ key[i].hex`, but that outputs an ASCII dec value.Can anyone help me out?

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to the suggestions below, I am able to run the following tests successfully:

```
def test_xor
    key = 'hi'
    msg = 'Hello There, how are you?'
    key_trunc = key
    key_trunc << key while key.length < msg.length
    key_trunc = Decrypt.truncate key_trunc, msg.length

    ct = Decrypt.xor msg, key_trunc
    assert_equal(['200c040507493c010d1b0d454801071e48081a0c4810071c57'], ct)
end

def test_decrypt
    msg = 'attack at dawn'
    key = '6c73d5240a948c86981bc294814d'
    key = [key].pack('H*')

    new_key = Decrypt.xor msg, key
    assert_equal(['0d07a14569fface7ec3ba6f5f623'], new_key)
    ct = Decrypt.xor 'attack at dusk', new_key.pack('H*')
    assert_equal(['6c73d5240a948c86981bc2808548'], ct)
end
```

For those interested, here is the successful Decrypt module:

```
module Decrypt

  # Returns an array of ASCII Hex values
  def self.to_dec_array(str_hex)
    raise ArgumentError, 'Argument is not a string!' unless str_hex.is_a? String

    dec_array = str_hex.unpack('C*')

    dec_array
  end

  def self.to_str_from_dec_array(dec_array)
    raise ArgumentError, 'Argument is not an array!' unless dec_array.is_a? Array

    return dec_array.pack 'C*'
  end

  def self.print_dec_array(dec_array)
    return [dec]
  end

  def self.xor(msg, key)

    msg = self.to_dec_array msg
    key = self.to_dec_array key
    xor = []

    (0...msg.length).each do |i|
      xor.push msg[i] ^ key[i]
    end

    xor = xor.pack('C*').unpack('H*')

    xor
  end

  def self.truncate(str, len)
    str = str.to_s[0...len] if str.length > len

    return str

  end

end
```

Comment: I've looked into `ord`, which seems like it may be what i need to use to get this working, but after reading about it and trying to implement it, I could not get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `to_hex_array` method you shouldn't be converting the bytes to strings (your call to `to_s 16`) - that's why you end up trying to xor strings rather than integers

That does mean that your `xor` method will need an extra step to turn the result from an array of integers to a string - something like

```
array_of_integers.map {|int| int.to_s(16)}.join
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get it working by changing `result` in `to_hex_array` to `result = str_hex.unpack('C*')`, then in `xor` I changed the final `xor` variable to `xor = xor.pack('C*').unpack('H*')`, which worked. However, I would like `to_hex_array` to return an array where each index position held a hex value, not a dec value, which `C*` returns (but returns as an array of individual indices, whereas `H*` returns an array of a single value, the entire hex string). Does that make sense?

Comment: an array of integers is neither decimal or hexadecimal - that's just how ruby chooses to print it to the screen

Comment: What I mean is that `unpack('C*')` returns to me an array that looks like `['75', '36', '72', '101'], and `unpack('H*')` returns to me an array that looks like `['6e32010a']`. I would like the hex representation returned to me as individual indices in the array such that the previous array becomes `['6e', '32', '01', '0a']`. But manipulating the hex array to split up its indices converts the values to strings, and I return to my original problem with XOR

Comment: Crucial difference - `"hi".unpack('C*')` returns returns [104,105] not ['104', '105'] (array of integers not strings). You don't need to convert them to hexadecimal

Comment: Thank you! That cracked it for me. I didn't notice that `unpack('C*')` wasn't returning string indices.